# jQuery tab_title already in use

Tags: custom-post-types, jquery

i am fetching data against a cpt in tabs so that when someone hover over a tab its content is shown in below div. now data is being fetched and when hover over tabs data bottom div also shows the text but instead of shwoing menu items in tab its giving me rror"The name tabs_title is already in use." . This is written on each tab instead of menu item this is my code to show tabs

```
<ul>
      <?php $args = array('post_type' => 'services', 'posts_per_page' => 7, 'orderby ' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC');

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    $i = 0;
    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    $i++;
      ?>
    <li>
        <a href="#tabs-<?php echo $i; ?>"  
        onclick="window.location='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'">
        <?php print_custom_field('tabs_title'); ?></a>
    </li>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  </ul>
```

Comment: `print_custom_field` isn't a WordPress core function, and that error is not an error message generated by core. I'll guess they are both related to a plugin, and if that's the case, you should ask the developer of the plugin.

Comment: Yeah was just about to ask - where is print_custom_field() coming from?

Comment: that  comes from  Custom Content Type Manager plugin